# Word count is incorrect when multiple spaces are present in the string

Tags: javascript, function

This function works fine.
But if i add more spaces in str than it gives the wrong count of words. Any help would be appreciated.

```
str = "coune me in"
var obj = {};
var regex = /[\s]/gi

function count(str){
    // total spaces in a string
    var spacesCount = str.match(regex).length;
    // words count
    var wordsCount = str.split(' ').length;
    //charetcers count
    var charsCount = str.split('').join('').length;
    //average count 
    var avgCount   = str.split(' ').join('').length/wordsCount;
    // adding it to the object  
    obj.words = wordsCount;
    obj.chars = charsCount;
    obj.avgLength = avgCount;
    obj.spaces = spacesCount;
    return obj

}
count(str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
mystring.split(/\s+/);
```

This will split on one or more white-space characters so two spaces (or more) in a row will be treated as just one split.

Answer (score 0):

```
let Allah = 'Allah    is our creator.'
Allah = Allah.trim();
count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < Allah.length; i++) {
    let char = Allah[i];
    if (char == " " && Allah[i-1] != " ") {//add here
        count++;
    }
    
}
count++;
console.log(count);
```

//output:4

Comment: not a good solution - e.g. exception when first char is space already...

Comment: Please check then send a screenshot.

Comment: haha, sorry, no exception there, but still a wrong solution, because if your 'Allah' starts with space, it returns the wrong count. 
if you want, i will send you a screenshot or you could try it yourself.

Comment: Please screenshot.

Comment: Just test it with `let Allah = ' test';` and see for yourself - count is 2 instead of one. If you wanna know why, feel free to start a new question.

Comment: @Homungus please check now.